# ucommerce weight property

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

does anyone know where to access the weight property for a uCommerce product.

I have implemented a custom shipping service based on weight but cannot find the weight section in the umbraco / ucommerce back office. I have no issue accessing it in code but as a logged in user it is hidden(to me anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible in version 2.6.x. A custom property will need to be created.